# __clone method is not making copy of class object

Tags: php

I want to use __clone() for making the copy of class object and after that i want to print that copy object.
here is code:

```
<?php
class Test {

    public static $counter = 0;
    public $id;
    public $other;


    public function __construct(){ 
       $this->id = self::$counter++;

    }

    public function __clone()
    {
       $this->other = $that->other;
       $this->id = self::$counter++;
    }
}

$obj = new Test();
$copy = clone $obj;
print_r($copy);
?>
```

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: What is `$that` suppose to be?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
$copy = $obj->__clone();
```

You should use

```
$copy = clone $obj;
```

The `__clone()` method is called when you call `clone`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you do not clone an object by directly calling its `__clone` method. You should use the `clone` language construct, like this:

```
$new = clone $old;
```

That will call your `__clone` method for you to do any additional work *after the object has been cloned*.

Something to note: In PHP, objects are assigned by reference. What this means is that if you clone an object `A` which has a variable pointing to an object `B`, modifying `B` on the original will affect the clone, and vice-versa.

The `__clone` method allows you to react when a clone is happening, so you can properly clone `B` as well. Like this:

```
class B { }

class A {
    public $b;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->b = new B();
    }

    public function __clone() {
        $this->b = clone $b;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$c = clone $a;

// now you can safely modify $c->b without worrying about $a->b
```

Note that this nesting should go as deep as you want to receive copies for. Anything else will be copied by reference and can cause headaches down the line. General rule of thumb: be careful with clone.